# puedo hacer un autorrelleno dinamico con macros?

Tags: excel, vba, macros, imacros

en este caso quisiera saber si puedo crear un rango dinamico en macro de excel con un autofill o autorrelleno.
quisiera saber si puedo seleccionar un rango dinamico por ejemplo (A1:A.End) espero puedan apoyarme en este caso

Answer (score 1):

Claro, tienes que calcular cual es tú ultima fila con datos y con eso montar tu rango:

```
Dim ultimafila as Long
Dim HojaDatos as WorkSheet
Dim MiRango as Range

Set HojaDatos = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MiHoja")
ultimafila = HojaDatos.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Set MiRango = HojaDatos.Range("A1:A" & ultimafila)

With MiRango
    
    'Aqui pones cómo quieres rellenar ese rango de celdas.
    .Value = "Hola"

End With
```

Saludos!

Comment: Yo añadiría que aparte de valores, puedes especificar formulas en formato R1C1 y llenar toda la columna con la misma fórmula en 1 línea de código. Buena respuesta